# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config; No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am also facing the same issue while running the script. I got this error message.

```
/content/gdrive/MyDrive/models/research/object_detection
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py:251: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
W0202 09:54:04.361228 139698941007744 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py:251: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 186, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 95, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 138, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 122, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config; No such file or directory
```

Comment: Open configuration file of your model, SSD model and your configuration file is `"ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config"`. Then open that file search `"label_map_path"` variable which gives path to pbtx file. Set exact path for it. It will work. Thanks!